# How to create a new scope in angular / angularstrap for a modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular-strap

I'm trying to create a service that will display certain modals and their corresponding templates along with automatically hooking up buttons to supplier event handlers. The problem I'm having is that when my modal pops up, and scope that should contain the handleConfirmClick and handleCancelClick are both null (looked at this using Batarang).

I'm using typescript, and I debugged the underlying JS code and saw that modalScope.handleConfirmClick is not null when I create the modal, but after creating it, the modal scope has both handle functions as null.

```
public createAndShowConfirmCancelModal(header:string, content:string, okClick:() => void, cancelClick?:() => void)
    {
        var modalScope = <any>this.$rootScope.$new();
        modalScope.handleConfirmClick = okClick;

        modalScope.handleCancelClick = () => {
            if (cancelClick != null)
            {
                cancelClick();
            }
            modalScope.$hide();
        };

//        modalScope.();

        this.$modal({
            scope: modalScope,
            show: true,
            content: content,
            title: header,
            container: '.contain',
            template: 'js/pages/components/confirmCancelModal.html'
        });
    }
```

Comment: Are you basing everything on batarang? You know batarang doesn't display function references, right? Does it explicitly say they are `null`, or shows an empty value?

Comment: I tried both setting a breakpoint, and the breakpoint isn't hit, and batarang shows null, not just empty.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have shown is valid.

$modal only creates a copy of your passed in modalScope using `$new` : https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/blob/master/src/modal/modal.js#L38 and should contain the functions `handleConfirmClick` and `handleCancelClick` on `__proto__`.

## Debugging suggestions:

Place a breakpoint in the browser dev tools at this point : https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/blob/master/src/modal/modal.js#L39 and print `scope.handleConfirmClick` and `scope.handleCancelClick`. Both should print the function bodies on the console. If so your error is not in *creating a new scope*.